# Can't Install Ubuntu On My Desktop

Tags: launcher, startup, bootloader

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

I Have tried to install Ubuntu via USB , and when i clicked **Install Ubuntu** on a hard disk . it starts like to load something and it freezes on a screen that says "detected 1024 MiB VRAM"  .Please HELP

My PC Specs:

Intel i3-2100 @3.1 GHz
8GB DDR3 Ram Memory
Nvidia GeForce GTS 450 Evga
60GB SSD  Hard disk
MSI h61m-p23(g3)  - Motherboard

Comment: Can you please describe in details whats happening.. when it get freeze at what point of screen.. please give as much detail as you can

Comment: Is In THe Screen Were is loading Like .. The One .. Purple .. And It Say ."Ubuntu 12.04 ...." And it Had like 4 points that shows that is loading up . It Last like a time there . but after . it start showing error. like . can't read block . something like that

Comment: I think your installer image is courrupt try it on some other PC if  its working. or there some fault in USB stick. format the usb stick with fat32 and make new bootable USB stick. It will work

Comment: check the [md5sum](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) of ISO image. if corrupt redownload and continue.

Comment: I Try It In A Virtual Machine. And It Also Give Me An Error While Installing . I Will Try Download The ISO File Again A This Time Use Other UBS . A SandDisk 16GB

Comment: I Check the md4sum file and it say that they are different then i download it again and it keep saying the same . I Will try with and older version of ubuntu